# Some interesting experimental results about the distribution of primes

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-gaps

Let's consider the following metric of the gap between consecutive primes
$$m(k)=\frac {p_k^2-p_{k-1}^2} {24}\;\;\;\;\;(k\ge4)$$

Now, let's define the function

$\delta(k)=m(k)\;\;\;\;$ if $\,m(k)\,$ is prime $\;\;\;\;(1)$

$\delta(k)=0\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$ otherwise $\,\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(2)$

If we plot the graph of $\,m(k)\,$ we obtain (up to $\,k=10^4$):

[image]

But, if we plot the graph of $\,\delta(k)$, we obtain **something completely different** (up to $\,k=10^4$):

[image]

> In the second graph the three different increasing curves seem to have
>   the following asymptotic behaviors:
>
> $$\sim \frac {p_k} {2}$$
>
> $$\sim \frac {p_k} {3}$$
>
> $$\sim \frac {p_k} {6}$$
>
> **Further, the prime numbers are not uniformly distributed among the three curves. The number of primes decreases passing from the highest
>   to the lowest curve** (I'm trying to estimate the number of primes that fall on each curve).
>
> I do not have adequate knowledge of analytic number theory to
>   explain the phenomenon, therefore I ask for your help.

Many thanks.

Comment: The asymptotic behaviors you got is just derived from the Cramer conjecture, and you have multiplied the equality of  Cramer conjecture by even integer which is p_k+p_(k-1) , Could you deduce some thing from the plot of Cramer  for your graph plot ?

Comment: Your question is not of research level. If $p_k-p_{k-1}=2$, then your expression equals $(p_k+p_{k-1})/12$, which is asymptotically $p_k/6$. Similarly, if $p_k-p_{k-1}=4$, then your expression is asymptotically $p_k/3$. Finally, if $p_k-p_{k-1}=6$, then your expression is asymptotically $p_k/2$. So what you observe follows easily from well-known conjectures on gaps between primes.

Comment: I read experimental evidence this way: if $\,m(k)\,$ is prime, then it will be $\,\sim p_k/2\,$ or $\,\sim p_k/3\,$ or $\,\sim p_k/6$, no other possibility given. The question is to estimate the probability of the three cases.

Comment: See my response below. It answers your question in full.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assume that $k\geq 5$ and $m(k)$ is prime. Observe the factorization
$$\frac{p_k-p_{k-1}}{2}\cdot\frac{p_k+p_{k-1}}{2}=6m(k).$$
On the left hand side, the second fraction is greater than $6$, hence the first fraction is smaller than $m(k)$. So the first factor is relatively prime to $m(k)$, whence it divides $6$. So $p_k-p_{k-1}$ equals $2$ or $4$ or $6$ or $12$.

- If $p_k-p_{k-1}=2$, then $m(k)=(p_k+p_{k-1})/12\sim p_k/6$.
- If $p_k-p_{k-1}=4$, then $m(k)=(p_k+p_{k-1})/6\sim p_k/3$.
- If $p_k-p_{k-1}=6$, then $m(k)=(p_k+p_{k-1})/4\sim p_k/2$.
- If $p_k-p_{k-1}=12$, then $m(k)=(p_k+p_{k-1})/2$, which is a contradiction, because there is no prime between $p_k$ and $p_{k-1}$.

This explains the "three increasing curves" $p_k/6$, $p_k/3$, $p_k/2$. The density of these three cases (i.e. the validity of two linear equations in the three primes $p_k$, $p_{k-1}$, $m(k)$) is heuristically known, see e.g. Conjecture 1.2 in [Green-Tao: Linear equations in primes](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0606088).